# Is it ok to use mutable to decrease all the keys in std::map by the same value?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap, stdset

As far as I know, std::map is almost always implemented as some kind of self-balancing search tree. Therefore, I assume decreasing every key by the same value should not result in undefined behaviors or corrupt the map? Is the following code actually safe?

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Key {
    mutable int val;
    bool operator<(Key const& other) const {
        return val < other.val;
    }
};
int main() {
    map<Key,int> mp {
        {{1},2},{{3},4},{{5},6},{{7},9}
    };
    for (auto&& kvp : mp) {
        kvp.first.val -= 2;
    }
    mp.emplace(Key{2},3);
    for (auto&& kvp : mp) {
        cout << kvp.first.val << ":" << kvp.second << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

// should print -1:2 1:4 2:3 3:6 5:9 
}
```

As for use cases, I think this might be useful to implement an event queue where each event is associated with a timer and will be fired if the timer reaches 0.

Comment: _"should not result in undefined behavior"_ that's not what UB means. You're violating the contract of `std::map` in an extremely egregious manner, no amount of "technically correct"ness is saving you.

Comment: If your problem is actually implementing event queue timers, consider a timer wheel as an alternative approach to this problem.

Comment: From https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#associative.reqmts.general-3 it just requires that *"For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value."*. But I would assume there has to be some sort of blanket rule that any `const` object (not reference) provided to a standard library feature can't spontaneously change value, though I couldn't find one.

Comment: Looks ok to me, but I don't see why you would want to use it. Just store the absolute time in each element.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I originally felt it might be more efficient because I can quickly find the last key with a value of, say, 0 without iterating through all the elements. 

But yeah I realized it's useless because I still have to go through the whole map to decrease the keys.

Comment: Yep, and the first/last elements are just `*m.begin()` and `*std::prev(m.end())`.

Comment: @PasserBy Could you please clarify which contract of `std::map` is violated?

Comment: What I was referring to was that the keys are immutable. Even if there is some loophole, I presume it's unlikely to be upheld in the case the standard library does depend on the immutability because that's not what's understood.